# How do I find all the NUMERIC columns in a table and do a SUM() on them?

Tags: postgresql, db2, comparison, netezza

I have a few tables in Netezza, DB2 and PostgreSQL databases, for which I need to reconcile and the best way we have come out with is to do a SUM() across all the NUMERIC Table columns on all the 3 databases.

Does anyone have a quick and simple way to find all the COLUMNS which are either NUMERIC or INTEGER or BIGINT and then run a SUM() on all these?

For comparing the results, I can do it manually also, or if someone has a way to capture these results in a common table and automatically check the differences in the SUM?

Comment: ...comparing sums might net you incorrect results.  For instance, if one row is later split into two, with half the value in each.  You've forgotten the `DECIMAL` type.  What about non-numeric data - why isn't that important?  What about setting up cross-db replication?  Also, **three** databases?  Regardless, you'd need some pretty hefty dynamic SQL to make this work.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse yes totally agree with that. have a lot of other tests also to determine the full stack, but right now looking only for SUM(). Have to do it across the 3, as we are migrating from Netezza to Cloud which has PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For DB2 you can use this metadata which will help you to find out the data type for each column

```
SELECT
               COLUMN_NAME || ' ' || REPLACE(REPLACE(DATA_TYPE,'DECIMAL','NUMERIC'),'CHARACTER','VARCHAR') || 
               CASE 
                              WHEN DATA_TYPE = 'TIMESTAMP' THEN '' 
                              ELSE
                                             ' (' ||
                                             CASE 
                                                            WHEN CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS VARCHAR(30))
                                                            WHEN NUMERIC_PRECISION IS NOT NULL THEN CAST(NUMERIC_PRECISION AS VARCHAR(30)) || 
                                                                           CASE 
                                                                                          WHEN NUMERIC_SCALE = 0 THEN ''
                                                                                          ELSE ',' || CAST(NUMERIC_SCALE AS VARCHAR(3)) 
                                                                           END
                                                            ELSE ''
                                             END || ')'
               END || ',' "SQLCOL",
               COLUMN_NAME,
               DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION, NUMERIC_SCALE, ORDINAL_POSITION
FROM SYSIBM.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'insert your table name'
AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'insert your table schema'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Answer (score 0):

For Netezza, I got the following query:

```
SELECT 0 AS ATTNUM, 'SELECT' AS SQL
UNION
SELECT ATTNUM, 'SUM(' || ATTNAME || ') AS S_' || ATTNAME || ',' AS COLMN
FROM _V_RELATION_COLUMN RC
WHERE NAME = '<table-name>'
AND FORMAT_TYPE= 'NUMERIC'
UNION
SELECT 10000 AS ATTNUM, ' 0 AS FLAG FROM ' || '<table-name>'
ORDER BY ATTNUM
```

Still looking how to do this across DB2 and PostgreSQL.